# Get Response Header with angular 2

Tags: angular, header, ionic2, token, response

I set the header response `Token: abc` from php. how to get the value from the response header? 
this my code

```
isLogin(): Promise<any> {
        let headers = new Headers;
        headers.set('Token', 'absajsj'); //I can set the header
        headers.get('Token'); // But this return NULL

        //console.log(this.cookie.get('autologin'));

        //let options = new  RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.get(this.BASEURL + 'api/client/authentication/check', { headers: headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                let a = res;
                console.log(a.headers.get('Token'))
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

this the server code. i use codeigniter.

```
if ($this->auth->loggedin())
        {
            $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(['status' => $_COOKIE['autologin']]));
        } else {
            $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_header('Token: abcks')
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode(['status' => $_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN']]));
        }
```

take your attention at `else` block.

and this the response header. i use firefox dev tools.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for 2 days. I have found this is a cors issue. And to solve this just to add `Allow-Origin-Header-Expose "Token"` in .htaccess

Thanks to u guys to give me attention. this community is awesome. I will mark this as the answer. Cheers :)

Comment: I had a slightly different issue where I needed to add "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", but you mentioning headers helped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use append method instead ?

```
headers.append('Token', 'absajsj');
```

Comment: yep, and no effect. :D
The response from the server is JSON

Comment: I test your code, and the get/set works.
Did you import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

Comment: Sorry. I was edited this thread. I mean i cant get the token from response header. The console is printed null..

Comment: You set the token in the request header... check if your response header contains the Token param with Fiddler.

Comment: What is fiddler? I can see the token in response header but cant get it.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
a.headers('Token')
```

Comment: It given err: cant invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Comment: can you print and post the res.headers object of the promise please

Comment: I was edted the script. The response is like the picture. There is no token in header